# Separate hash that has comma separated value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash that has multiple value separated by comma but I need to separate it into single hash for each value.

Currently I have this hash:

```
{"key"=>"value,value1,value2", "key1"=>"value,value1,value2", "key2"=>"value,value1,value2"}
```

Is there a way to separate it to single hash for each value like this:

```
[{"key"=>"value", "key1"=>"value", "key2"=>"value"}
{"key"=>"value1", "key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value1"}
{"key"=>"value2", "key1"=>"value2", "key2"=>"value2"}]
```

Any idea is welcome, Thanks!

Comment: Do the values in each hash actually correspond/match like they do in your example?

Answer (score 1):

```
h = { "key" =>"value,value1,value2",
      "key1"=>"value,value1,value2",
      "key2"=>"value,value1,value2" }
```

```
g = h.transform_values { |v| v.split(',') }
  #=> {"key"=> ["value", "value1", "value2"],
  #    "key1"=>["value", "value1", "value2"],
  #    "key2"=>["value", "value1", "value2"]}
```

```
g["key"].size.times.map { g.transform_values(&:shift) }
  #=> [{"key"=>"value",  "key1"=>"value",  "key2"=>"value"},
  #    {"key"=>"value1", "key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value1"},
  #    {"key"=>"value2", "key1"=>"value2", "key2"=>"value2"}]
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

Comment: Thanks also for the reference @CarySwoveland, slight changes on last part `g.keys.size.times.map { g.transform_values(&:shift) }` but working now. Thanks!

Comment: I see, you're right. I tried to test it with another `value3` and i only got 3. I removed the checkmark for now. But I can use your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this might be overly complicated and might need some tweaks, but here's another option that seems to get the job done and works for more than 3 values so long as the length of values is always the same:

```
h = {"key"=>"value,value1,value2,value3", "key1"=>"value,value1,value2, value3", "key2"=>"value,value1,value2,value3"}
        
h.values.each_with_index.map {|v, i| v.split(",").map {|e| {h.keys[i] => e}}}.transpose.map{|x| x.inject(&:merge)}.join("\n")
        
#=>  
{"key"=>"value", "key1"=>"value", "key2"=>"value"}
{"key"=>"value1", "key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value1"}
{"key"=>"value2", "key1"=>"value2", "key2"=>"value2"}
{"key"=>"value3", "key1"=>" value3", "key2"=>"value3"}
```